# fail to connect to mysql using mysql++

Tags: mysql, sql, connection, mysql++

my calling code is as following

```
bool suc = conn.connect("mydb", "localhost", "root", "");
if (suc)
{
cout << "success" << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "fail " << conn.error() << endl;
}
```

and mysql server is running , but the program fails saying 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (111)

Has anyone met such a problem?

Comment: Either the socket file is not in /tmp, or mysql isn't running. If it was connecting but couldn't log in, you'd get permission denied instead. The socket file is highly unlikely to be in /tmp, since that dir can get auto-cleaned by the OS. It's most likely somewhere likely somewhere in `/var`, but you'll have to check the mysql .cnf/.ini file to see what it really is.

Comment: I have /tmp/mysql.sock file, and mysql is running too, I can log in using the username root and empty passwd. wait, what's the full path of .cnf/.ini, i want to go for a check

Comment: Can you connect to it with the `mysql` command line program?

Answer (score 0):

The Mysql config file is likely located here /etc/my.cnf

If Mysql is running, it might be helpful to look at the log, it should be located in /var/log/

Named something like:
mysql.log
mysql.err
mysqld.log
mysqld.err

```
$ ls -l /var/log/
// when you have the name try
$ tail -n 50 /var/log/LogName
```